# Declared and initialised variable returning values when printed

Tags: c++, variables, printf, declaration

The issue arises with the variable `shortestval` below. It's declared and initialised (at 1000) below.

```
ENSEMBLE Cscan = *C;
ENSEMBLE Vscan = *V;
int departnumero = Vscan->numero, arrivenumero = Cscan->numero, departshortest, arriveshortest;
double shortestval = 1000;
LISTE aretescan = NULL;

int x=0, y=0, z=0;

while( (*C) != NULL && iteration < 100){
iteration++;
departshortest = 99;
arriveshortest = 99;

printf("\n\n shortestval = %i", shortestval); // Check 1

while(Vscan != NULL && x < 100){
    printf("\n\n\t shortestval = %i", shortestval); // Check 2
    while(Cscan != NULL && y < 100){
        printf("\n\n\t\t shortestval = %i", shortestval);// Check 3
        aretescan = aretes[Vscan->numero];
        while(aretescan != NULL && z < 100){
            printf("\n\n\t\t\t shortestval = %i", shortestval);// Check 4
            if(aretescan->arrive == Cscan->numero){
                if(aretescan->cout <= shortestval){
                    printf("\n \t\t\t (%d < %d)", aretescan->cout, shortestval);

                    shortestval = aretescan->cout;
                    departshortest = aretescan->depart;
                    arriveshortest = aretescan->arrive;

                }
                printf("\nD - %d \tA - %d \tC - %d", aretescan->depart, aretescan->arrive, aretescan->cout);
                printf("\t\t\tD - %i, A - %i, C - %i", departshortest, arriveshortest, shortestval);
            }

            aretescan = aretescan->suiv;
            z++;
        }
        Cscan = Cscan->voisin;
        y++;
    }
    Vscan->voisin;
    x++;
}
```

However at `// Check 1` immediately after, the value printed is '0'. This continues until `while(aretescan != NULL && z < 100)` loop, in which the line:

```
printf("\n \t\t\t (%d < %d)", aretescan->cout, shortestval);
```

prints -858993460 for `shortestval`, before the line

```
printf("\t\t\tD - %i, A - %i, C - %i", departshortest, arriveshortest, shortestval);
```

print a value of 5 for the first iteration of the while loop, which is what I was expecting it to be (this is the value of `aretescan->cout` that `shortestval` was set to). But repeatedly, it seems that in the `if(aretescan->cout <= shortestval)` seems to repeatedly take shortestval to = 858993460, or failing that a very high value as every iteration it re-assigns itself as per the operation that depends on the if statement but by the time the next iteration comes around it continues to be read as this mystery value.

I'm completely stumped. Any ideas would be heartily appreciated.

Comment: Why are you printing a double variable 'shortestval' with an exclusively integer format specifier '%i'? It is no wonder your check printouts produce meaningless output.

Answer (score 1):

`shortestval` needs to be declared `int`, not `double`. All the rest of the code seems to treat it as an int.

**Edited to add:**

> `printf("\n \t\t\t (%d < %d)", aretescan->cout, shortestval);` prints as -858993640

`-858993640` = `0xCCCCCCCC`, which is probably what the runtime library is using to fill unused or uninitialized memory; so you've probably failed to initialize `aretescan->cout` properly.

As @Matts Petersson points out, LISTE.cout might be the wrong datatype.

I can't tell what `aretescan = aretes[Vscan->numero];` does without seeing the definition of `LISTE`.

**Edited to add:**

If `aretescan->cout` and `shortestval` really are `double`, then use `%f` in the `printf()` statements, not `%i` or `%d`:

```
printf("\n \t\t\t (%f < %f)", aretescan->cout, shortestval);
```

Comment: I changed 'shortestval' to 'int' and it initialised correctly as 1000.

'printf("\n \t\t\t (%d < %d)", aretescan->cout, shortestval);' prints as -858993640 and everywhere else it was printed as -2147483648 every time.

Comment: And what is `aretescan->cout`'s type and where is it being set?

Comment: `aretescan->cout` is in fact a `double` but having gone through the code, reset `shortestval` to `double` and tidied up the printf outputs, I'm still getting bizarre numbers at

`printf("\n \t\t\t (%d < %d)", aretescan->cout, shortestval);`

Answer (score 0):

That sounds like either (a) a memory stomp, (b) aretescan->cout is not a %d. Given check 1 it's more likely to be a, probably a broken implementation of ENSEMBLE::operator=().

```
ENSEMBLE Cscan = *C;
char _pad1[1024];
ENSEMBLE Vscan = *V;
char _pad2[1024];
int departnumero = Vscan->numero, arrivenumero = Cscan->numero, departshortest, arriveshortest;
char _pad3[1024];
int shortestval = 1000;
char _pad4[1024];
LISTE aretescan = NULL;
char _pad5[1024];
```

and change check 1

```
printf("\n\n shortestval = %u", shortestval); // Check 1
```